# Mockito mocked function returned Null

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, mockito, tdd

I got stuck on making the test using Mockito. I'm trying to implement Clean Architect to the Flutter tutorial https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/codelab. I've made a use case called `GetRandomWords` and an interface-adapter called `RandomWordsRepository` like so:

```
abstract class RandomWordsRepository {
  String get();
}

abstract class GetRandomWords {
  String randomWords();
}

class GetRandomWordsImpl implements GetRandomWords {
  final RandomWordsRepository repository;

  GetRandomWordsImpl(this.repository);

  @override
  String randomWords() {
    return repository.get();
  }

}
```

I've made a test case like this:

```
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:tutorial/domain/interfaces/random_words_repository.dart';
import 'package:tutorial/domain/use_cases/get_random_words.dart';

class MockRandomWordsRepository extends Mock implements RandomWordsRepository {
}

@GenerateMocks([RandomWordsRepository])
void main() {
  setUp(() {});

  test("Should get random words from repository", () async {
    final expectedRandomWords = "test_random_words";
    final mockRepository = MockRandomWordsRepository();
    final useCase = GetRandomWordsImpl(mockRepository);
    when(mockRepository.get()).thenReturn(expectedRandomWords);
    
    expect(useCase.randomWords(), expectedRandomWords);
    verify(mockRepository.get());
  });
}
```

But it returned this error: `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'` on the line `when(mockRepository.get()).thenReturn(expectedRandomWords);`. Can anybody tell me what went wrong here?

Comment: Minor point. You're not implementing clean architecture. You didn't pass in a Presenter. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/420360/24365

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are following some old Mockito example that predates Dart null-safety.

With null-safety, you should *not* be defining the `MockRandomWordsRepository` class (or other mock classes) yourself.  You instead will need to *generate* the mock classes with `@GenerateMocks([RandomWordsRepository])` or `@GenerateNiceMocks([RandomWordsRepository])` and then running `dart run build_runner build`.  You then will need to add an appropriate `import` line to use the generated file.

Make sure that you follow [the instructions from the Mockito `README`](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito#lets-create-mocks) precisely.